# show value in specific column from all tables sql

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I dont know how to ask this question so I'll just tell you guys exactly what i am doing.

I have 10 tables with columns called "names", "prices" and "location". 5 of those columns have string value "apples" and the other five have string values  "oranges". i am looking for an sql query that can select all from all tables where names is "oranges" so it displays 5 items with their prices and location.

For example:

SELECT * from database.ALLTables WHERE names = 'oranges'.

so it displays all information from only tables containing the value Oranges.
I am very new to sql and its for an android app.

sorry if I'm not clear enough and thanks for the help.

Comment: All I can say is you have a totally messed up database. Please read a primer of database schema design

Comment: Your column names aren't clear. You say you have ten tables with the columns called  "names", "prices" and "location". but then you try a where on a column called "name" not "names". Which is it?

Comment: its names sorry I didnt write it correctly I just fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using UNION.

e.g.

```
SELECT names, prices, location FROM table1 WHERE name = 'oranges'
UNION
SELECT names, prices, location FROM table2 WHERE name = 'oranges'
UNION
SELECT names, prices, location FROM table3 WHERE name = 'oranges'
...
```

Comment: '$sql = "SELECT * FROM phone where username = '".$id."'" UNION SELECT * from user WHERE username='".$id."'";' i tried it like that but it doesn't work. its for an android app and i'm using JSON if it helps

Comment: The number of columns from the selects have to match up. Because you have SELECT * you are selecting all columns from those tables, the count might not match up.

Comment: i finally got it working using your suggestion. It was an error on my part thats why it didnt work. i added one extra quotation mark which caused the error. thanks for the help. I am bad at posting quotes for now so i cant show exactly what i corrected but once I learn it, i'll update the post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Another idea is to use

```
SELECT *
    from (
    SELECT * from database.tabe1
    union
    SELECT * from database.tabe2
    union
    SELECT * from database.tabe3
    union
    ..
    ..
    ..
    SELECT * from database.tabe10
    )
WHERE name = 'oranges'.
```

Comment: This won't work as his tables don't contain the same amount of columns.
Also, using the series of subqueries eliminates the need to use a where on each individual query but it will be selecting all rows from the subquery tables before union which will be slower.

Answer (score -1):

Please try following query :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE names='orange'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE names='orange'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE names='orange'
UNION
-
-
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableN WHERE names='orange'
```

If any confusion let me know.
Thanks...

Comment: This won't work as his tables don't contain the same amount of columns.